# I have django application and nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I have `django` application and `nginx`, from browser, it access to the file /static.

such as

```
http://example.com/static/file.png
```

However my application has files under /staticroot.

```
http://example.com/staticroot/file.png
```

it shows the image.

So, I set on `nginx`.

```
location /static {
    alias /staticroot;
}
```

However it doesn't appear

My environment is Debug mode.

My settings py is like this,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(config("PROJ_PATH"), 'staticroot')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you run `collectstatic`...??

Comment: YES I run `collectstatic` and files are stored in `/staticroot` already

Comment: alias /entire directory path/staticfiles/;

Comment: you have to alias you entire path of the static file something like '/home/youprojectdic/static/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serve  **staticroot** content you've to rename your `STATIC_URL='/staticroot/'` & in nginx file make changes like this

```
location /staticroot/ {
    alias /home/your_username/project_name;
}
```

When request comes to `/staticroot/somefile` **Nginx** will look for directory named as **staticroot** in file system and it will serve provided file. 
So when you define url for your static or media content make sure you've created directory with the same name.
For more info check [Serving Static Content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) on Nginx docs.

Answer (score 2):

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/you_project`
set

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/your_admin_name/your_project_folder_name;
}
```

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```